# Deploy the updated file rather than the whole project/folder

Tags: google-app-engine, deployment

When you edit a single file on your project and deploy the project to the Google App Engine, are all the files deployed? If so, can I limit the deployment to the updated file to save time and bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like an old question, but from my understanding the answer is No. Only the updated files will be deployed and therefore you should save time and bandwidth.

Thanks.